# Post Correspondence Problem, $(1101, 1),(0110,11),(1,110)$

Tags: number-theory, logic, algorithms

I'm trying to solve a **Post Correspondence Problem**, $$(1101, 1),(0110,11),(1,110)$$

I'm not aware of any method of telling if this has a solution aside from trying different sequences. So I tried

$$1101.1.1.0110.$$
$$110.1.110.110$$

I think that's correct or am I wrong?

Comment: But all my $x$ and $y$ numbers match up, so why would that be?

Comment: I though that you can mix and match the $x$ and $y$ values, so long as you don't mix them together, to come up with a solution. Do you have to use $x_1$ and $y_1$, $x_2$and $y_2$, ... together?

Comment: Yes, the stones are fixed. Imagine you have arbitary many stones of the $3$ given sorts. You have to put some of them together such that (without considering spaces) the two words coincide. You know that PCP is undecideable in general ? This one seems to be unsolveable.

Comment: That's perfect! Would you mind putting in the answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is that you have arbitary many stones of the given sorts. You have to put finite many together in such a way that (not considering spaces) the created words coincide.

According to my PCP-solver, this problem has no solution within $200$ moves, so I guess it is not solveable. It might be interesting to prove this. Perhaps I will try to find a proof.

PCP is undecideable in general.